# WOOCOMMERCE call function from URL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a php function that creates a new session (WC()->session->set).

I want to make a link on site's header that calls a function to remove that session ( WC()->session->set( 'the_session', null );

how it should be done? couldn't find a way :(

tried to use $_get on functions, which didn't work

EDIT:

here is the code Im using, it add's the option to edit orders that have been made already:

```
/**
 * @snippet       Edit Order Functionality @ WooCommerce My Account Page
 * @how-to        Get CustomizeWoo.com FREE
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=91893
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 4.1
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */
  
// ----------------
// 1. Allow Order Again for Processing Status
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_order_again', 'bbloomer_order_again_statuses' );
  
function bbloomer_order_again_statuses( $statuses ) {
    $statuses[] = 'processing';
    return $statuses;
}
  
// ----------------
// 2. Add Order Actions @ My Account
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'bbloomer_add_edit_order_my_account_orders_actions', 50, 2 );
  
function bbloomer_add_edit_order_my_account_orders_actions( $actions, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) {
        $actions['edit-order'] = array(
            'url'  => wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( array( 'order_again' => $order->get_id(), 'edit_order' => $order->get_id() ) ), 'woocommerce-order_again' ),
            'name' => __( 'שנה בחירה', 'woocommerce' )
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}
  
// ----------------
// 3. Detect Edit Order Action and Store in Session
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'bbloomer_detect_edit_order' );
             
function bbloomer_detect_edit_order( $cart ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['edit_order'], $_GET['_wpnonce'] ) && is_user_logged_in() && wp_verify_nonce( wp_unslash( $_GET['_wpnonce'] ), 'woocommerce-order_again' ) ) WC()->session->set( 'edit_order', absint( $_GET['edit_order'] ) );
}
  
// ----------------
// 4. Display Cart Notice re: Edited Order
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_show_me_session' );
  
function bbloomer_show_me_session() {
    if ( ! is_cart() ) return;
    $edited = WC()->session->get('edit_order');
    if ( ! empty( $edited ) ) {
        $order = new WC_Order( $edited );
        $credit = $order->get_total();
        wc_print_notice( 'A credit of ' . wc_price($credit) . ' has been applied to this new order. Feel free to add products to it or change other details such as delivery date.', 'notice' );
    }
}
  
// ----------------
// 5. Calculate New Total if Edited Order
   
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'bbloomer_use_edit_order_total', 20, 1 );
   
function bbloomer_use_edit_order_total( $cart ) {
    
  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
     
  $edited = WC()->session->get('edit_order');
  if ( ! empty( $edited ) ) {
      $order = new WC_Order( $edited );
      $credit = -1 * $order->get_total();
      $cart->add_fee( 'Credit', $credit );
  }
    
}
  
// ----------------
// 6. Save Order Action if New Order is Placed
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'bbloomer_save_edit_order' );
   
function bbloomer_save_edit_order( $order_id ) {
    $edited = WC()->session->get( 'edit_order' );
    if ( ! empty( $edited ) ) {
        // update this new order
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_edit_order', $edited );
        $neworder = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $oldorder_edit = get_edit_post_link( $edited );
        $neworder->add_order_note( 'Order placed after editing. Old order number: <a href="' . $oldorder_edit . '">' . $edited . '</a>' );
        // cancel previous order
        $oldorder = new WC_Order( $edited );
        $neworder_edit = get_edit_post_link( $order_id );
        $oldorder->update_status( 'cancelled', 'Order cancelled after editing. New order number: <a href="' . $neworder_edit . '">' . $order_id . '</a> -' );
        WC()->session->set( 'edit_order', null );
    }
}
```

I want to make a button on my website header, that removes the session after the user clicked "edit order", if he decided to cancel the editing and stay with his original order, the line that does that is

```
WC()->session->set( 'edit_order', null );
```

and I want it to be a link

Comment: Hey Lidorkalfa - it would be awesome if you could show us what you tried that didn't work. Not only will it help us understand the problem you're trying to solve - but StackOverflow is not really a place meant to do the programming for you - so much as help you understand why yours isn't working!

Comment: @Ryan Your'e right, its the second or third time Im writing here - its pretty new to me,
I've edited the original question :)

Comment: Either use a specific URL parameter, something like `href="?clear_my_WC_session=1"`, and then check for that in a general location like your functions.php; or set up an actual REST API endpoint and target that with your link. (In that case, you'd have to redirect somewhere else afterwards.)

Comment: @CBroe done that in functions.php:

// leave 'choose new gift' session - use on a button on header
function leave_edit_order(){

    $edited = WC()->session->get('edit_order');

    if(!empty($edited))
    {
        WC()->session->set( 'edit_order', null );
    }
}

 if($_GET['cancel_edit_order'] == 1){
   leave_edit_order();
 }


the url works, but when calling the function i get fatal error on wordpress :(

Comment: So enable WP debug mode, and check what the logs have to say.

Answer (score 0):

Found the right way:

```
add_action('afterheader','leave_edit_order');

function after_header_block_yhm()
{
     do_action( 'afterheader'); 
}

add_shortcode('under_header_location','after_header_block_yhm');



function leave_edit_order(){

    $edited = WC()->session->get('edit_order');

    if(!empty($edited) && isset($_GET['cancel_edit_order'])){

                WC()->session->set( 'edit_order', null );
                wc_print_notice( 'You left "edit order" session, enjoy your stay.' );

    
}
add_action('afterheader','leave_edit_order');
```

Made a new action called 'afterheader" and a new shortcode called 'under_header_location',
then used elementor to put the shortcode in the place I wanted, and then called the function in that new action I made

on the function Im checking that the user has ?cancel_edit_order on his url and then calling the function